# Stop iTunes from loading everytime I connect the iPhone

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, iphone

I'm on Windows XP and whenever I connect the iPhone, iTunes loads up automatically.

How do I stop it from loading up every time I connect the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Disable Automatic Syncing of iPods and iPhones will stop this, in Preferences. I remember having this same issue and it doesn't happen for me anymore.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open iTunes
2. Plug in your iPhone or iPod
3. Under Devices (In the left hand column), Select/Highlight your iPhone or iPod
4. Summary tab > Options > Uncheck "Open iTunes when this iPod/iPhone is attached"

The image below is for an iPod (iTunes 9.0.3), but it should be similar for an iPhone:

[image: Don't open iTunes when I connect my iPhone/iPod]

Comment: Where is that? I have the newest version of iTunes on Windows and don't see that under Devices.

Comment: Your iPhone isn't showing up under devices?

Comment: Confirmed. It's not there.  I think, it's been replaced with 'Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected'.

Comment: I have that option also - I may not have explained where to find the setting very well.

The Devices I'm talking about is the section in the left column of iTunes - not the Devices tab in the iTunes Preferences.

Comment: The options are different for iPhone's - there's only a "Automatically sync when connected", which is annoying