# How do I stop iTunes from opening when I connect my iPad?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, ipad

This is on Windows 7 x64 if that makes any difference.

[This related question](https://superuser.com/questions/121929/how-to-stop-itunes-from-loading-up-everytime-i-connect-the-iphone) says to *Disable Automatic Syncing* in the Preferences, but that option is grayed out for me.

Is there a way to do this with iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution that works for the iPhone: [Prevent iTunes from starting when iPhone is plugged in on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/55390/prevent-itunes-from-starting-when-iphone-is-plugged-in-on-windows)

Comment: Killing iTunesHelper.exe worked. SCORE